# Why self-service password reset in Azure B2C defaults to off?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have been using the old way of resetting passwords in Azure B2C, namely when the user clicks the forgot password link on a Sign Up Sign In user flow (hereafter Susi), the B2C endpoint throws back to the app, and from this app we catch the error and redirect to a reset action in an account controller that essentially will point to a reset password flow.

Now it seems that from version 2.1.3 onward of the built-in Susi user flows we can opt for an option `self-service password reset` that as such does not throws back to the app but rather stays on the endpoint on the same susi flow.

However, this option is not set by default. Given that it simplifies the flow, I wonder why it is not set by default?

From a security and B2C perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before 2.1.3 version, password reset experience throws an error code AADB2C90118 , which is returned to application and application used to handle this error code  reinitializing the authentication library to authenticate an Azure AD B2C password reset user flow, so if we provide this option by default there could be conflict with the existing self service password reset flow, in my view hence it is not turned on by default.